# A custom jax-rs entity provider for an interface?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

How can I tell RESTEasy (a jax-rs implementation), "Hey, when you get asked for `IFoo`, just go ahead and make a `Foo` object?"

## My current (erroneous) attempt

I have an api access point that I would like to consume `ReportPieceDAO` objects.  `ReportPieceDAO` has as a `List<StandardScoreReport>` member.  `StandardScoreReport` is an interface, implemented by `StandardScoreReportImpl`.

```
@Path("pieces")
@PUT
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Iterable<Long> putReportPiece( List<ReportPieceDAO> reportPieces) {
    return getDataCoordinator().updateReportPieces(getAuthenticatedUser(), reportPieces);
}
```

This entry point worked well before I added the `List<StandardScoreReport>` member.  Because `StandardScoreReport` is an abstract interface, RESTEasy can't automatically construct one - it complains that `StandardScoreReport` has no default constructor.

So, I wanted to make some sort of adapter or provider that constructed a `StandardScoreReportImpl` in cases where a `StandardScoreReport` was required:

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/json")
public class StandardScoreReportProvider implements MessageBodyReader<StandardScoreReport>{

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> arg0, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2,
            MediaType arg3) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public StandardScoreReport readFrom(Class<StandardScoreReport> arg0,
            Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2, MediaType arg3,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> arg4, InputStream arg5)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

            //I'm hoping I can just call some "default" code that 
            //would run if StandardScoreReportImpl were naturally 
            //encountered, and not have to write my own unmarshalling code.

        return new StandardScoreReportImpl();
    }

}
```

But none of this code is ever executed.  Here's my application description:

```
public class RESTEasyApplicationDescription extends Application
{
    HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public RESTEasyApplicationDescription()
    {
        classes.add(APIRoot.class);
        classes.add(ReportsRoot.class);
        classes.add(StandardScoreReportProvider.class);
        classes.add(StandardScoreReport.class);
        classes.add(ReportPiece.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Providers are registered when you deploying the application to the server. The server automatically know how handle receive / deliver a certain object.
You must create a class that has the `@Provider` and then if you

> Create a java object from POST you may use: @Consumes 
>   Send a java object to Response from a webservice call you may use: @Produces

and specifying the type.

**Example:**
I have a service that gives me a PDF when I call, it's no consumes nothing, it's only give to me a pdf file:

**MyService.java**

```
@GET
@Path("/report.{format}")
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML, "application/pdf" })
public Response recuperarReporte(){
    private ByteArrayOutputStream responseEntity = ....;
    Response
            .ok()
            .entity(responseEntity)
            .type("application/pdf").build();
}
```

**MyPDFProvider.java**

```
@Produces("application/pdf")
@Provider
public class MyPDFProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<ByteArrayOutputStream>
{

    @Override
    public long getSize(ByteArrayOutputStream stream, Class<?> type,
            Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return stream.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return ByteArrayOutputStream.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream t, Class<?> type,
            Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException
    {
        entityStream.write(t.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! I just updated my question to be more specific about my situation - I don't need a way to write an object to an output stream, but rather a way to read specific objects from an input stream.  I'd like to map all instances of `StandardScoreReport` to the default `StandardScoreReportImpl` deserializer.